# jsonlite - toJSON is adding .1, .2 to duplicate list names

Tags: r, jsonlite

I'm looking to format some JSON for an API call in R.

The section of the code I want to convert to JSON looks currently looks like this:

```
list(request = list(passengers = list(adultCount = "1")),

        slice = c(
            list(origin = origin1, 
                 destination = origin2,
                 date = depart_date
                 ),
            list(origin = origin2, 
                 destination = origin1,
                 date = return_date
                 )),
        solutions = "100"
            )
```

Using lists and vectors has worked for me in the past but I didn't have any duplicate key names in my pre-convert data.

Now that I do, the output when I use toJSON() appears like this:

```
{
 "request": {
     "passengers": {"adultCount": "1"}
             },
   "slice":
 {
   "origin": origin1,
   "destination": origin2,
   "date": depart_date,
   "origin.1": origin2,
   "destination.1": origin1,
   "date.1": return_date,
 },
 "solutions": "100"
}
```

The .1 being appended to the key names is not only collapsing the structure of the JSON, it's also giving me an invalid key name.

How am I to go about fixing this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? Do you want `slice = list(...)` rather than `slice = c(...)`?

Comment: Changing from a vector to list fixed my output! Thanks!